# How to access history or recently closed tabs in Chromer

Tags: browser, crashes, history, browser-tabs

I use Chromer in web heads mode. Occasionally I have had all web-heads disappear, presumably due to a crash. In past sometimes Chromer suggested me to reopen old tabs when restarted but not today.

Is there a way to make it reopen recently closed tabs without being prompted? I cannot find anything like that in the menus.

Comment: Did you browsed in an incognito tab/window??

Comment: @parthu_panther I have found the way to open history but it would stiil be nice to reopen the lost session in one go. I had a lot of tabs open and am not sure which ones I had dealt with already. Exporting the history to my computer would also make it easier to see where I left off.

Comment: The sessions might would have been closed as the app got crashed. If the crash was due to a minor environment conflict than you could have regain your sessions, but as you stated in the question that you cant find anything in the menus suggest that the crash was not a usual crash and as a result the browser refreshed all the ongoing sessions.

Comment: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1012716] Here is a solution available for mozilla firebox browser. Try it with your stats. Good luck. peace..